# Find the Limits of Integration of $\,r=2+5\sin \theta$

Tags: calculus

If you're trying to find the area within the inner loop for the polar curve $r=2+5\sin \theta$, how would you find the limits of integration? 
I attempted letting $2+5\sin\theta = 0$, but this gives $\sin \theta = -2/5$ which seems messy and incorrect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't say any information about the $\text{dom}(r)$ that is the range of $\theta$. Otherwise, $r$ may be negative (like when $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{2}$). Also, it's easy to compute the area under the polar coordinate (just add a Jacobian Determinant, here is $r$). You may write your equation like
$$
S=\int_x \int_y dx dy=\int_\theta \int_r rd\theta dr=\int_\theta d\theta\int_r rdr=\int_\theta \frac{1}{2}r^2 d\theta
$$
where $r=2+5\sin \theta$. Plugging $r$ into the above equation and you could compute the area $S$.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want values for $\theta$ between $0$ and $2\pi$.  If $\sin \theta =-2/5$, then my calculator says $\theta = -0.4115\ldots$, which is not in the range.  But the angles $\pi+0.4115\ldots$ and $2\pi - 0.4115$ have the same value for sine.  Those two numbers are your limits of integration.